# IE - Margin:0; CSS rendering issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am having a very strange rendering issue with the latest IE (don't know about others).

This is how it looks in chrome (correct way): https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdCA8.png

Now take a look at IE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7fLZ.png (disregard the thingy in the corner, not an issue)

But here is where the weird part comes in, when I uncheck and recheck `margin:0;` in dev tools (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjr4d.png), it formats correctly. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLBex.png

Any ideas what is causing it and how to fix it? I want to use javascript as last resort and avoid it if possible.

A bit long but here is the full CSS responsible for the menu:

```
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > ul {
  display: block;
}
.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-right: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-top: 1px solid #1682ba;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  background: #36aae7;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #1fa0e4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
.holder {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.holder::after,
.holder::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.holder::after {
  top: 17px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover > span::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a > span::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a > span::after {
  border-color: #eeeeee;
}
.holder::before {
  top: 18px;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-top-color: inherit;
  border-left-color: inherit;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-left: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-right: 1px solid #32373e;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #49505a;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.open > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
  background: #424852;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last.open > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 11.5px;
  border-top: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-left: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li.open > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li > a:hover::after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<img src="img/sidelogo.png" width="50%" />
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#' class="sb-close"><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Labs</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Experiments</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#' class="sb-close"><span>Exp 001</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#' class="sb-close"><span>Exp 002</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#' ><span>Projects</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='//knyz.org/design/Deep Space/' class="sb-close"><span>Deep Space</span></a></li>
               <li><a href='//knyz.org/design/Deep Space Dark/' class="sb-close"><span>Deep Space Dark</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='//mdd.knyz.org/' class="sb-close"><span>MDD</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='docs' class="sb-close"><span>Documents</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#' class="sb-close"><span>Archives</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#' class="sb-close"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vtqa9p1r/ seems to work ok in IE11?

Comment: @joshhunt strange, try making a full html page. JSfiddle might be handling the issue

Comment: Any luck with replicating it?

Comment: @joshhunt Here is the live version: http://knyz.org/labs/

Comment: Seems to be an IE bug, looks like it works in IE Desktop but not in the IE App. I've messaged someone from IE to see if they have any ideas.

Comment: @joshhunt Please get back to me. It is not a critical issue but can mess things up once I start developing on the template along with making me feel powerless against this issue.

Comment: @ViruZX Just wanted to update this thread; I am the one Josh reached out to. I can confirm that this is a bug in the layout sub-system of Internet Explorer. I was able to resolve the top-level menu by merely moving the CSS files after jQuery. But this doesn't resolve the sub-menu system. I'll continue to reduce the issue, and involve our layout Program Managers as well.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Can you either drop me an email at slava[at]knyz.org if you get a fix for the issue? Or simply reply to this right here.

Comment: @ViruZX I plan on posting any solution I come across here. One thing is certain, I will be opening an issue in IE to have this resolved on our end once I reduce the root-issue. If I do come across a work-around, I'll share it here.

Comment: I think that this is an Internet Explorer issue, although when I tested it out in IE11 it worked just fine.

Comment: URL to live version does not work ?

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi Yeah that's the thing with live versions... Plus it already clear the it is an IE issue so nobody apart from Jonathan can help by fixing up IE

Comment: have you tried any hacks for just focusing on ie?
this site has some great stuff, you might find what you need
http://browserhacks.com/

Comment: @arg0 Great resource! But sadly it does not help the issue at hand